# Accidentally wiped Cordova project

Tags: xcode, cordova

I wrote "cordova prepare ios" in my terminal console, unaware that it would wipe my project.
I do have a copy of my javascript file, but my css and html file are gone.
It happened 5 minutes ago. Is there any possibility in getting these files back? If so, how?

I worked 6 months on that project.

I did not press the "Build"-button, so the application on my iPhone is still with the original files.

I'd really appreciate any help.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Simply restore your files using your computer's backup, or your source control system, or your Xcode snapshot. You are using all of those, right?

Comment: Won't help you now, but this is a great reason for using something like git to keep a history of your code.

Comment: If you aren't using any of the three forms of backup I listed then no, there's no way to get your files back other than typing them over from scratch. Actually, I guess there is a fourth. Did you copy the files to a web server or some other folder? Or maybe part of a previous build somewhere?

Comment: does something like this help if you still have the app on the device: http://www.guidingtech.com/30623/backup-restore-apps-ios-without-itunes/

Comment: @rmaddy F**k yea, I just recovered the files by using Spotlight searching for "name.app" and than just opened the package content. Wuuh, I am going to enable computer backup soon, but right now I need a break from that little heart attack.

Comment: @VladStirbu Thank you for your contribution, I haven't looked at your link but I guess it is something similar like I wrote above.

Comment: it might be better to answer yourself to the question. by default only the first 4 comments are shown and the solution is not visible

Comment: just a side note : cordova prepare ios wiped your project because you put your project files in the platforms/ios folder instead of using www at the root of the project. That's how the CLI work. If you work in the platforms/ios folder you will have the problem again when you will want to add plugins...

Comment: @VladStirbu Yes, I know. I shifted that part, because I need a break after heart attack incidents like this - will do now.

Comment: @QuickFix No, adding plugins did never cause this and is still not causing my projects to be wiped. Adding plugins works fine. Also I thought the other www folder does not work? At least back with Cordova 3.0 the changes in the index.html in root www did not apply.

Comment: depends how you add plugins. if you use the cli (cordova plugin add...) the plugin is not actually added to the platform unless you call `cordova prepare ios` or `cordova build ios`which would overwrite the content of the platforms/ios/www with the content of  the root www folder. This has not changed since 3.6.0. If you use plugman to install the plugin directly for your platform, then you don't need cordova prepare, and I guess you build directly in xcode.

Comment: if you have made an ipa of that project before than you can unzip it and can have access to all your files and code from ipa

Comment: @AdarshNahar look at my comment above, I already found a solution. And also look at my answer below, my solution is similar to yours, just with the .app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I did it.
If you deleted your projects original content, but have not compiled the app yet, you can easily recover your work by following these steps:

- Open Stoplight and enter `"appname".app`
- Show all results in Finder and **right click your .app file** (If you find multiple select the one with the most current "Modified"-timestamp)
- Click "**Open enclosing folder**"
- **Right click** the .app file now in the newly opened window and click "**Show package content**".

Bam, all your files are there. Just copy them back into your project folder.

Comment: Worked like a charm. I lost all my www folder files, Almost had an heart attack. You saved me from lot of trouble. Thank you

Comment: @g4genuis You are very welcome. I am happy my instructions are still helpful 7 years after posting this :)